Webflow Tab Data Change
Dropdown Change with it's Data
All Data and Image will be changed.Here we have three item.When any user change data for comperision. it only change one row data.Also It's change it's image also when anyone changed the packages.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
